# iOS : code creates two NSTimers

Tags: ios, nstimer

When I create a new timer with an IBAction and I double click the button, it creates two timers.
How can I write the code so there's only 1 timer and if I push the button it doesn't create a new timer?

Sorry for my bad English I'm 13 and from Germany.

Here is the code I use to create the timer:

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
{
   progressBarUpdate = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.003 target:self selector:@selector(progressbarupdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   //startet den timer 
}
```

Comment: Don't create the second one if you've already created the first one.

Comment: why to write some shit under someones legit question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

safe the timer as a member variable and check if already exists

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    NSTimer *_timer;
}

...

- IBAction)start:(id)sender {
   if(!_timer) {
      _timer = [[NSTimer timerWith...] retain];//with arc, forget the retain
   }
}

...

@end
```

Comment: viel Spass auf StackOverflow! :)

Comment: now if i invalidate the timer i cant start the timer again! how can i write the code so that the timer is startable after i stopped it with [progressBarUpdate invalidate]                                    sumarized: i want to start the timer, then stop it and then start it again, start stop start stop . i think you know what i mean. all this without creating double timers... i think you know what i mean

Comment: Check isValid instead of the pointer. Like the other answer proposes

Comment: Instead of if(!_timer) check if(!_timer.isValid)

Answer (score 0):

Check progressBarUpdate.isValid before recreating the timer is an easy way to do this

Comment: well.. to nitpick :P this checks if the timer is scheduled on the runloop, not if it was CREATED before :D ... **but that is likely what he wants** so it is ok